# Why is my R.flatten(R.map(R.prop returning and undefined object here? RamdaJS

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

https://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/EgvBpx

As I understand it, I'm just passing my comboTags array in. The data is always curried into the right side of a Ramda statement.

I'm expecting `flatTags` to contain an Array of `tag1` and `tag2`

[image]

```
const comboTags = [
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: 'tag1'
      }
    ],
    person: {
      name: 'Jerry'
    }
  },
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: 'tag2'
      }
    ],
    person: {
      name: 'Laura'
    }
  }
];

const flattenTags = container => R.flatten(R.map(R.prop('tags')));

let flatTags = flattenTags(comboTags);
console.log('flatTags',flatTags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `pluck` also note usage of `compose` alternatively use `pipe`! This allows for point-free functions: [Try It Out](https://runkit.com/57eea0f0f5fa9d1400823806/57eea0f0f5fa9d1400823807)

```
const comboTags = [
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: 'tag1'
      }
    ],
    person: {
      name: 'Jerry'
    }
  },
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: 'tag2'
      }
    ],
    person: {
      name: 'Laura'
    }
  }
];

const getTagNames = R.compose(R.pluck('name'), R.flatten, R.pluck('tags'))

getTagNames(comboTags) // ['tag1', 'tag2']
```